# SQL, convert integer for Timestamp subtraction

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-timestamp

Assume we have a relation R(A, B), with
A contains int values and B contains Timestamps.

We have to calculate: `(time in B in minutes) - (int to minutes)`.

Example:
`(125, "2017-06-01 16:23:00")`

```
16:23:00 = 983 min
125 = 125min
```

983 - 125 = 858min

The elements of A represent minutes, my problem is to convert an integer
value `>59` to `hh:mm`, since `MAKETIME(hh, mm, ss)` only works in the range 0 to 59.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (MAKETIME is product specific.)

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly do you mean by tag and

Comment: Fixed by the unnamed horse. (The blue box with the text "mysql", next to the "sql" and "sql-timestamp" tags.)

Comment: I see, i forgot the correct tag.

Comment: `MAKETIME(858 / 60, 858 % 60, 0)`

Answer (score 2):

There's no need at all to convert the time of your timestamp column in minutes.

Just do

```
SELECT B - INTERVAL A MINUTE;
```

If you really just want the time to be subtracted from do

```
SELECT TIME(B) - INTERVAL A MINUTE;
```

To let the date part be untouched:

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATE(B), ' ', TIME(B) - INTERVAL A MINUTE);
```

**When you absolutely need the minutes afterwards:**

```
SELECT HOUR(TIME(B) - INTERVAL A MINUTE) * 60 + MINUTE(TIME(B) - INTERVAL A MINUTE);
```